# Shapefiles of the UK

Tags: shapefile, data, united-kingdom

I'm revisiting GIS after several years of not using it and have opted for QGIS (currently v2.14). All the example files I have are of the US (Alaska) but I am learning QGIS for work purposes. I live in the UK so want to find a shapefile of the UK mainland. It doesn't have to be anything fancy just an outline would do, and also ideally in the British National Grid CRS (although I understand you can reproject but I haven't figured out how yet!)

Does anyone know where I can get shapefiles of the UK for use in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @TheRobster! Perhaps this post might help: [UK coastline shapefile?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127959/uk-coastline-shapefile)

Comment: This [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177741/looking-for-a-free-shapefile-of-the-european-countries) should help too

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [datasets](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) available from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/). If you select your country (United Kingdom), you will access to data (as raster or vector maps) about:

- Administrative areas;
- Inland waters;
- Roads;
- Railroads;
- Elevation;
- Land cover;
- Population.

For example, this is the shapefile of administrative areas at the upper level (i.e. at the boundary level):

[image]

The CRS for all the data is WGS 84, but you can easily convert them to your preferred CRS by right clicking on their name in the **Layers Panel**, then by clicking `Save as…` and finally by selecting the target CRS in the options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are vast sources of open data for you to use.

Here are a few sites:

1. https://data.gov.uk/
2. http://www.diva-gis.org/Data
3. http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/
4. http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/
5. http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps, more specifically http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/biogeographical-regions-europe-3

Answer (score -1):

[image: Uk Boundary Shapefile]

You can get free shapefile to download from https://www.igismap.com/united-kingdom-shapefile-download/. It's completely free. Here you get polygon shapefile and shapefile of states.